# Firebase admin Java: How to have database reference with dynamic query

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

In javascript I can do this:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.handleUserActivityUpdate = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}/{activityId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    var userId = event.params.userId;
    var activityId = event.params.activityId;
});
```

Is there a way of doing the same in Java? I tried the following but it's not working:

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users/{userId}/{activityId}");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Get key: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            } finally {
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first bit of code looks like it runs on Cloud Functions for Firebase.  That currently only supports JavaScript - there is no Java yet.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson Yes the javascript code runs on Cloud Function. I've modified my data structure in order to use the second code.

Comment: You can't deploy Java code to Cloud Functions.  There is only support for JavaScript running in a managed node.js environment.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson your comments answer my question.